# ScrollView in Tabbed TVOS App

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, tvos

I am having some issues with the `UIScrollView` within a `tvOS` tabbed application.  The scrollView will scroll, but not until I "Tap" the trackpad, hiding the Tab Bar at the top.  I then can scroll, but if I accidentally click too high on the trackpad, it changes focus to the Tab bar again.  All I have edited on viewDidLoad for the scrollView is to allow indirect touches.  I tried `_scrollView canBecomeFocused = YES;` but it gave me errors of "Use of undeclared identifier canBecomeFocused" on that line.  Thoughts on making this scroll view easily scrollable without being a frustrating nightmare?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

_scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:UITouchTypeIndirect]];